# How to expose age range in views?

Tags: views

I'm trying to add an exposed filter for an age range with the Views module.

I made a **select age field** for age 18 to 80, but I can't find how to add a **filter range** in views.
For Example, I would add a filter saying "from age_**_ to age__**".

Answer (score 3):

- From the filter criteria choose the age field tick the exposed filter.
- Choose grouped filters from the filter type to expose.
- Choose the widget type. Then add values after changing the operator to 'is between'

Answer (score 0):

If you tick 'Expose this filter...' then click **Grouped filters** then you will be able to input some custom filter options, for each option you can do a 'between' filter.

Answer (score 0):

IN filter criteria just change the Operator from the default into "is between", It can give you ability to input the expose filter with min and max, eg. min =18 , max=80.

Comment: I don't see the "is between" Operator

Answer (score -1):

I would give this module a shot: [Views Contextual Range Filter](https://drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter)

Module Page Description:

> Views Contextual Range Filter is a simple plugin for Views that adds
>   the option to contextually filter not just by a single value, but also
>   by range.
>
> Numeric, alphabetical (string) and list ranges are all supported. Node
>   ids, user ids and even taxonomy term ids are all special cases of
>   numbers so will work also. Range-filtering on the "created" (posted)
>   and "updated" (last modified) node properties is also supported,
>   provided you use the correct format as dictated by Views. So, YYYYMMDD
>   for full dates or one of the shorter formats, i.e. year+month,
>   year-only, month-only, week-only or day-only.
>
> You may use the OR operator (i.e. +) and the negate operator. You
>   negate by ticking the "Exclude" box on the Views Contextual filter
>   configuration panel, in the "More" section.

Comment: Module Page Description: is also said " Please be aware that contextual filters are different from exposed filters. This module is about contextual filters only. " and this question is about Exposed filters